# O que é callback server-to-server?

Tags: api, terminologia, callback

Gostaria de saber se é um conceito, estou utilizando um serviço que me informou que as informações podem ser obtidas via callback server-to-server, porém não entendi exatamente o significado do termo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode especificar a URL / ponto de extremidade / callback que deseja que seja notificado com esse retorno de chamada após a conclusão de alguma tarefa.

Também é chamado de 
`Callback URL`

Por exemplo, seu sistema pode fazer a chamada da API de terceiros, e nesta chamada especificar um Callback para quando algum evento ocorrer, esta sua URL ser chamada:

```
POST /api.example.com/foo?callbackURL=http://my.server.com/bar
```

Fonte: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347056/what-is-a-callback-url-in-relation-to-an-api